# multiple table make my data alsp multiply

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
$get = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT supplier.*,product.* FROM 
supplier,product ORDER BY supplier.supplierid ASC");
$option = '';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($get, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $option .= '<option value = "' . $row['productname'] . '">' . 
        $row['suppliername'] . '</option>'; 
}
<label style="margin-left:25px;margin-bottom: 10px; ">Supplier:
</label><select style="margin-bottom:10px ;margin-left: 50px;width: 
200px"> <?php echo $option; ?></select>
```

Hello Maam And Sir I have A problem About that data Output In a Select Box. The thing that happen when i use this code or use two multiple table, the data output also double but if 1 table it is working the way i want. But I don't want to have a dirty codes that why i  to put in a single query.

Comment: If I understood you right, you're looking for [JOINs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)?

Comment: that thing is only have 3 data in product table and 2 for supplier.. but the  output is 6 but i only call the row of product as i understand ... and if i make them bot 3 for product and 3 for supplier it makes 9... they make the other one on how many loop.. :(

Comment: Can you add the structure of the product and supplier table to your post above?

Comment: This is an implicit cross join. You need to add the criteria that connects the 2 tabls in your where clause, or refactor it into a join and put the criteria in an ON clause.

Comment: What you need to is join tables on some unique data to match them. So check this it may help: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp